# GridView - hold more offscreen views?

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with an adapter for a grid view. The adapter causes a bitmap to be loaded every time a particular item is needed. I've got a disk cache and memory cache and I'm disabling loading while scrolling, so generally speaking, the gridview is quick.

But what I'd really like is to eliminate constantly having to rebind a particular Bitmap to an ImageView. Since the gridview is reusing views, the getView method has to keep reseting the ImageView and reloading the image from memory. This creates a really stupid effect as items slide offscreen and when returned to have a delay as the bitmap is read from the memory cache and posted to the ImageView.

Is there a way to get the GridView to 'hold on to' more views instead of being really frugal? I have a maximum of about 20 items and im scaling all the bitmaps, so I'd really like to just hold on to more of the views if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a better in memory cache. The real distinction was to add a mechanism to check if the image was in memory and not 'reset' the view if the required image was in memory. It still seems bogus that there is not an easy way to set the number of cached views off screen for grid view, but better memory cache management made the problem less noticeable.